# Parallax effect, text hiding under photo

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a parallax effect, but, if I create some content like text, tabs etc., they're hiding under the photo.

I followed a [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CQ7DYni7Bg), took it step-by-step, but it doesn't work.

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="widht=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Detail Software</title>
    <link rel = "icon" href =  "obrazky/DSico.ico" type = "image/x-icon"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Detail Software</h1>
        <p>Sense for detail.</p>
    </header>
    <div class="text">
        <h3>Forbes is an American business magazine owned by Integrated Whale Media Investments and the Forbes family. 
        Published eight times a year, it features original articles on finance, industry, investing, and marketing topics. 
        Forbes also reports on related subjects such as technology, communications, science, politics, and law. Its headquarterey. 
        Primary competitors in the national business magazine category include Fortune and Bloomberg Businessweek.
        Forbes has an international edition in Asia as well as editions produced under license in 27 countries and regions worldwide.
        The magazine is well known for its lists and rankings, including of the richest Americans (the Forbes 400)
        of the America's Wealthiest Celebrities, of the world's top companies (the Forbes Global 2000), Forbes list of The World's Most Powerful People
        and The World's Billionaires.[4] The motto of Forbes magazine is "Change the World".[5] Its chair and editor-in-chief is Steve Forbes
        it was sold to a Hong Kong–based investment group, Integrated Whale Media Investments</h3> 
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body{
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    perspective: 1px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-family: fantasy;
}
header{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 30vw 0 5vw;
    position: relative;
    transform-style: inherit;
    width:  100vw;
}
header h1{
    margin-top: -100px;
}
header, header:before{
    background: 50% 50% / cover;
}
header::before{
    bottom:0;
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    background-image: url(obrazky/1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    transform-origin: center center 0;
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    z-index: -1;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
header * {
    font-weight:  normal;
    letter-spacing:  0.2em;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em 0;
}
.text {
    color: grey;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  perspective: 1px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: fantasy;
}

header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 30vw 0 5vw;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: inherit;
  width: 100vw;
}

header h1 {
  margin-top: -100px;
}

header,
header:before {
  background: 50% 50% / cover;
}

header::before {
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0301/0065/files/fall_background_image_landscape_tree_lake_mountain_scene_web_2048x2048.jpg?16615717205281063826);
  background-size: cover;
  transform-origin: center center 0;
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  z-index: -1;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header * {
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

.text {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Detail Software</h1>
  <p>Sense for detail.</p>
</header>
<div class="text">
  <h3>Forbes is an American business magazine owned by Integrated Whale Media Investments and the Forbes family. Published eight times a year, it features original articles on finance, industry, investing, and marketing topics. Forbes also reports on related
    subjects such as technology, communications, science, politics, and law. Its headquarterey. Primary competitors in the national business magazine category include Fortune and Bloomberg Businessweek. Forbes has an international edition in Asia as well
    as editions produced under license in 27 countries and regions worldwide. The magazine is well known for its lists and rankings, including of the richest Americans (the Forbes 400) of the America's Wealthiest Celebrities, of the world's top companies
    (the Forbes Global 2000), Forbes list of The World's Most Powerful People and The World's Billionaires.[4] The motto of Forbes magazine is "Change the World".[5] Its chair and editor-in-chief is Steve Forbes it was sold to a Hong Kong–based investment
    group, Integrated Whale Media Investments</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a separate div for the background instead of `header::before`. Then add `position: fixed` and remove the unnecessary `transform` properties:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: fantasy;
}

header {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 30vw 0 5vw;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: inherit;
  width: 100vw;
}

header h1 {
  margin-top: -100px;
}

header,
header:before {
  background: 50% 50% / cover;
}

.parallax {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0301/0065/files/fall_background_image_landscape_tree_lake_mountain_scene_web_2048x2048.jpg?16615717205281063826);
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header * {
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em 0;
}

.text {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="parallax"></div>
<header>
  <h1>Detail Software</h1>
  <p>Sense for detail.</p>
</header>
<div class="text">
  <h3>Forbes is an American business magazine owned by Integrated Whale Media Investments and the Forbes family. Published eight times a year, it features original articles on finance, industry, investing, and marketing topics. Forbes also reports on related
    subjects such as technology, communications, science, politics, and law. Its headquarterey. Primary competitors in the national business magazine category include Fortune and Bloomberg Businessweek. Forbes has an international edition in Asia as well
    as editions produced under license in 27 countries and regions worldwide. The magazine is well known for its lists and rankings, including of the richest Americans (the Forbes 400) of the America's Wealthiest Celebrities, of the world's top companies
    (the Forbes Global 2000), Forbes list of The World's Most Powerful People and The World's Billionaires.[4] The motto of Forbes magazine is "Change the World".[5] Its chair and editor-in-chief is Steve Forbes it was sold to a Hong Kong–based investment
    group, Integrated Whale Media Investments</h3>
</div>
```